# ionic 3 angular 4 creating animation on row delete

Tags: angular, ionic3

In my ionic 3 angular app. This app is currently built for the browsers. There is a popover which displays an array of data in the form of a ion-slide. so let's say there are 3 records in the array. So, naturally the ion-slider shows 3 slides one at a time. When i switch from one slide to another using the bullets the transitions between the slides is nice pleasant.

There is a capability to delete the current slide. Which is done by clicking  a button in each slide. This basically removes the row from the array. This is show fast that user doesn't notice sometimes that the current slide is gone. How do i make a smooth visual effect to make it noticable?

The current ion-slide is like:

```
  <div class="popup-layout">
    <ion-slides pager='true'>
      <ion-slide *ngFor="let recAct of optyRow.recommendedAction">
          <ion-row class="popup-layout-header">
            <ion-col text-left>
              <ion-label class="popup-header-text">{{recAct.title}}</ion-label>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-grid no-padding>
        <ion-row><ion-col text-wrap text-left>
        <ion-label style="font-size:small">{{recAct.desc}}</ion-label>
        </ion-col>
        </ion-row>

        <ion-row no-padding>
          <ion-col col-auto ><icon-button [iconName]="actionTaken" [data]="recAct" (onClickedActionTaken)="onClickedActionTaken($event)"></icon-button></ion-col>
        </ion-grid>
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
</div>
```

The triggered event is:

```
 onClickedActionTaken(id){
    this.optyRow.recommendedAction = this.optyRow.recommendedAction.filter( item => {
            return item.id != id;
        })
  }
```